# Org-mode export minted block with options

Tags: emacs, org-mode

According to [this file](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/ox-latex.el;hb=HEAD), if I export something like this:

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS: tufte

#+ATTR_LaTeX: :options label={asdf}
#+begin_src c
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
#+end_src
```

The relevant part of the generated `tex` should be this, if I understand correctly:

```
\begin{minted}[frame=lines,linenos=true, label={asdf}]{c}
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
```

However, the exported `tex` hasn't got the `label` part. It seems it is being ignored.

Any ideas how to fix this?